# Portlet @resourceMapping and Multipart as parameter

Tags: java, liferay

I use Liferay and I have code:

```
@ResourceMapping(value = "keaFileUpload")
public ModelAndView fileUpload(ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response,
                                   ModelMap modelMap) throws PortalException, SystemException {
// code
}
```

How can I use Multipart as parameter request? For example MultipartHttpServletRequest?
When I use it instead of ResourceRequest request I have error.

Answer (score 0):

When the form is multipart/form-data you should get extra parameter(like "name") from UploadPortletRequest instead of ResourceRequest.

correct form of getting parameter:

```
UploadPortletRequest uploadRequest = PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(request);
String name = ParamUtil.getString(uploadRequest,"name");
```

Also you can check out this link

https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/17237791